# Laravel IoC on helper class unit test

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, tdd, laravel-5

I'm creating a helper class to work with `Filesystem`, that gets injected via Laravel IoC like this:

```
// MyHelperClass
public function __construct(Filesystem $filesystem) {
    $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
}
```

The problem is I have no idea, nor I can find any documentation on how to instantiate `MyHelperClass` inside a `TestCase` subclass. I tried `IoC`'ing it in the `__construct(MyHelperClass $myHelperClass)` and `setUp(MyHelperClass $myHelperClass)` methods but that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the test classes are resolved out of the IoC container, so they wouldn't support automatic dependency injection. If you want your class resolved out of the IoC container you can use `App::make('MyHelperClass')` or `$this->app->make('MyHelperClass')`. (And of course if it's in a namespace make sure to include that.)